# How to change address in the hex view in IDA debugger?

Tags: ida, windows, debugging, windbg

I'm just learning the IDA pro debugger, so I apologize if this is something simple. Say, if I opened a debugee process and started stepping through it with a debugger (WinDbg) and then want to look up the contents of memory. How do I change the address in the hex view pane?

(Circled in red in this screenshot)

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Click on the hex view plane and press <kbd>G</kbd> to change the address.

Comment: IDA Pro has such a HORRIBLE user interface! Instead of using cryptic keyboard shortcuts there should be an option in the right click menu "Enter address" or "Jump to User Address". The IDA pro GUI is one of the worst that I have ever seen.